# I have followed a tutorial online on how to make a FPS controller getting 3 cs1003 error codes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, syntax-error

## This is the code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GD_FirstPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Walkspeed = 5f;
    public float SprintMultiplier = 2f;
    public float JumpForce = 5f;
    public float GroundCheckDistance = 1.5f;
    public float LookSensitivityX = 1f;
    public float LookSensitivityY = 1f;
    public float MinYLookAngle -90f;
    public float MaxYLookAngle  90f;
    public Transform PlayerCamera;
    public float Gravity -9.8f;
    private Vector3 velocity;
    private float verticalRotation = 0f;
    private CharacterController characterController;

    void awake()
    {
        characterController = Getcompoent<characterController>();
        Cursor.LockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    }


   void update()
    {
        float horizontalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalMovement = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 moveDirection = transfrom.forward * verticalMovement + transform.right * horizontalMovement;
        moveDirection.Normalize();
```

*I Have followed this tutorial line for line and have re-watched it over and over again to fine no error/difference in our code still getting 3 cs1003 error codes and really dumbfounded on what to do next.

Comment: Help us help you - share the errors

Comment: `public float MinYLookAngle -90f;`  There need to be a `=` in that line (somewhere...., but of course on the right position!)